# Several nested if conditions

Tags: c#, if-statement

I have five conditions that I have to check (i.e does the user want to search using this field or not). There are four combo boxes and one text field. The user can search using any field or multiple fields as they please. To check which field the user selected I have constructed several if and else if statements. But when doing so for only two conditions I realized how tedious task this will be for five conditions is there a better way to do this?

```
if  (cmbAgent.Text=="")
{
    if (cmbDegree.Text=="")
    {
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM UniversityData", connection);
    }
    else
    {
       OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM UniversityData WHERE Expertise LIKE '%" + cmbDegree.Text + "%' ", connection);
    }
}
else if(cmbDegree.Text=="")
{
    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM UniversityData WHERE SourceOfContact LIKE '%"+ cmbAgent.Text + "%' ", connection);
}
else
{
    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM UniversityData WHERE SourceOfContact LIKE '%" + cmbAgent.Text + "%' and Expertise LIKE '%" + cmbDegree .Text + "%' ", connection);
}
```

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but you should probably go and read about [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and how to prevent it before this code is deployed to production.

Comment: Refactor. http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/consolidateConditionalExpression.html and http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/consolidateDuplicateConditionalFragments.html

Comment: Please use full uppercase for the command keywords like `SELECT` , `FROM` and so on.. It makes it easier to understand the command quickly. :)

Comment: @Amit : except that it's a different query for each condition.

Comment: Seems like a mild XY Problem. What feature are you trying to provide to the user? Perhaps checkboxes aren't the most effective way of doing that from a UI perspective, which will then simplify your code allowing you to avoid this problem all together.

Comment: @MalteR That's a matter of taste.  All my SQL is written in lowercase...

Comment: @JamesThorpe Yes of course. W3C uses all uppercase, and i think it makes it faster to see the keywords and understand the command.

Comment: @MalteR The W3C?  Or w3schools/fools... I let my IDE highlight the keywords to me, rather than having them shout at me :)

Comment: @MalteR : to see and understand the keywords and commands, you just have to arrange/indent your query correctly. You don't _have_ to write them uppercase. In fact, depending on the query length/complexity, and table/fields case, it's sometimes easier to read when it's all lower-case.

Comment: @cosmo0 Sure, i just find it to be an easy way of spotting the keywords fast. I also split my commands and indent them, depending on their length/complexity. It might be easier to _read_ when in all lowercase though

Comment: @cosmo0 - It is not different query. Filters are getting changed. Refactoring it , he can apply filters on built query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What if the user needs/wants to enters several values ?
You can easily build the query dynamically.

By the way, you should use query parameters to prevent SQL injection.

```
// the "where 1=1" allows to always concatenate "and xxx"
// instead of testing if there were fulfilled conditions before
var query = "SELECT * FROM UniversityData WHERE 1 = 1";

var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();

if (txtDegree.Text != "")
{
   query += " AND Expertise like '%' + ? + '%' ";
   parameters.Add("degree", txtDegree.Text);
}

if(txtAgent.Text != "")
{
    query += " AND SourceOfContact like '%' + ? + '%' ";
    parameters.Add("agent", txtAgent.Text);
}

OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, connection);
// add the parameters
foreach (var p in parameters) {
    da.SelectCommande.Parameters.Add(p.Key, OleDbType.VarChar, p.Value);
}
```

Note that OleDb doesn't support named parameters. If you can, I would consider switching to Sql commands and adapters.

By the way, if you ever can/want to use Linq to build your queries (through Entity Framework for instance, or any other ORM), you can do it, too, since Linq and Entity Framework together are late-bound (meaning the query is not executed until the results are actually read).

```
// build the query
var results = from ud in context.UniversityData
              select ud;

if (txtDegree.Text != string.Empty) {
    results = from ud in results
              where ud.Expertise.Contains(txtDegree.Text)
              select ud;
}

if (txtAgent.Text != string.Empty) {
    results = from ud in results
              where ud.SourceOfContact.Contains(txtAgent.Text)
              select ud;
}

// use the results
myControl.DataSource = results.ToList(); // the ToList() call actually calls the query
```

Comment: Finally an Answer that prevents SQL Injection the proper way.

Answer (score 3):

That is why most build query/query string separately. Example:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("Select * from UniversityData where 1 = 1");
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cmbDegree.Text.Trim())){
    sb.Append(" and Expertise like '%" + cmbDegree.Text + "%'")
}
//...
var querystring = sb.ToString();
OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(querystring);
```

Answer (score 2):

I would do something like this:

```
var query = "Select * from UniveristyData";
var wheres = new List<string>();
if (!cmbDegree.Text.IsNullOrEmpty())
    wheres.Add("Expertise like '%" + cmbDegree.Text + "%'");
if (!cmbAgent.Text.IsNullOrEmpty())
    wheres.Add("SourceOfContact like '%"+cmbAgent.Text+"%'");

if (wheres.Any())
    query += " where " + string.Join(" and ", wheres);

var da = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, connection);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could build a key-value List first:

```
List<Tuple<string, string>> keyValueList = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();

keyValueList.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("Expertise", cmbDegree.Text));
keyValueList.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("SourceOfContact", cmbAgent.Text));
```

and so on and then construct your Where-Clause out of the keyValueList :

```
var conditionsArray = keyValueList.Where(p => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(p.Item2)).Select(q => q.Item1 + " LIKE '%" + q.Item2 + "%'").ToArray();
```

And finally:

```
var sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM UniversityData WHERE " + string.Join(" AND ", conditionsArray);
```

You need to add checks, if the array is empty before adding the WHERE-clause etc., but I doubt you need help with that :-)

To add more conditions, you just need to add more Tuples to the keyValueList (1 line) and no need to change the other code later.